# DOMPDF Chinese Character

Tags: php, html, dompdf

I have problem that when I download the PDF it will download the font together in the PDF which will create a very big size of PDF (about 10mb+).

```
<?php
include "/dompdf_config.inc.php";
$html =
  '<html><body><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <style>
  *{ font-family: simsun; }
  </style>
  <p>开发人员指南</p>
  </body></html>';

$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("hello.pdf"); ?>
```

Comment: So, what exactly is your question?

Comment: Sorry for that, my question is "how to not download the font together in the PDF which will make the PDF file size become very big".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to enable font subsetting.

In dompdf 0.6.2 or earlier set the `DOMPDF_ENABLE_FONTSUBSETTING` configuration constant to true. Configuration constants can be set in dompdf/dompdf_config.custom.inc.php.

In dompdf 0.7.0 or later after you instantiate dompdf you can configure this option using the set_option method: `$dompdf->set_option('isFontSubsettingEnabled', true);`.

Comment: I will get error like this "Warning: fopen(/dompdf/lib/fonts/simsun.ttf.tmp.3189616819): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /dompdf/lib/php-font-lib/classes/font_binary_stream.cls.php on line 75 Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /dompdf/lib/php-font-lib/classes/font_binary_stream.cls.php on line 149 Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in..........."

Comment: solved! thank you for your guide. The reasons why I got the error is because dompdf dont have permission to access.

Answer (score 0):

follow the procedure to  use chinless language support in laravel latest version

1. clone https://github.com/dompdf/utils
2. download font from  i use  simsun  https://www.wfonts.com/font/simsun
   3.1.keep those file in project root folder
   3.2 add folder name font in storage folder
3. Run  php load_font.php "Simsun" Simsun.ttf from your comment pomp
   5.then use in html body { font-family:  'Simsun'; } for chines[image] language
   6.i attach image so that it will help you
   [image]